# ibatis typehandlers: Why implement a valueOf ()

Tags: ibatis

There is not much documention regarding type handlers in `ibatis`. I wanted to ask when implementing custom typehandlers, why do we need to implement a `valueOf()` function. I get the reasoning behind `getResult` and `setParameter`.
Thanks